# how should i find a global key in flutter driver test?

Tags: flutter-test, flutterdriver

Normally I put Key: ValueKey in a flutter element that I want to find in my test cases for testing, however this particular element already has a globalKey. So, what should I use to find the globalkey used in the element?

> value key

`key: ValueKey('nameField')`

In test case =>
`final nameField = find.byValueKey('nameField')`

> global key

`final LabeledGlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>> _passwordField = LabeledGlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>>("passwordFieldKey")`

`key: _passwordField`

In test case =>
`final passwordField = find.???('???')`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to find a `GlobalKeys` (that I used to find the position of certain widgets), but what you can find is `Key`s. So what I did is: Wrap the widget that I had to find in my test by a Container Widget that had that `GlobalKey`.

```
GlobalKey someKeyName = GlobalKey();

Container(
    key: someKeyName,
    child: CustomButton(
      key: Key('Key that I would look for in my Integration Test'),
      child: Text('Press Me'),
    ),
);
```

I am not sure of what `LabeledGlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>>` does, but hope this work around will help you solve your issue.